# How to wrap a .c native library method in Objective-C class

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a pure c method that converts wav to flac. I need to use this functionality in Xamarin MonoTouch project. Xamarin allows binding to Cocoa Touch Static Libraries, where method definitions are written in objective-c, not pure c.

So in XCode, I've assembled a Cocoa Touch Static Library project, that has the .h and .c files of the native functionality in place. I've also set everything up to build a "fat" multi-platform library in a form of .a file.

Now the single method I need to expose via objective-c looks the following way in .h declaration:

```
int sprec_flac_encode(const char *wavfile, const char *flacfile);
```

I assume I could just write a wrapper function for this native function in objective-c class and just call that obj-c wrapper from my .net binding.

How would the aforementioned declaration wrapping look in objective-c?

**Additional info**

I know I can just wrap a native c method. I used an automated tool to generate a wrapper in C#. And it resulted in a method declaration of a following form:

```
[DllImport ("/Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/iOSNative/SpeechRecognitionC/GoogleSpeechRecognizerC/GoogleSpeechRecognizerC/flac_encoder.h")]
int Sprec_flac_encode (ref string wavfile, ref string flacfile);
```

.Net compiler doesn't seem to understand this type of DllImport call and therefore I think I'd be able to wrap in obj-c and have that exported to .net, then to try to figure out how to fix the DllImport.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that Xamarin allows you to bind Objective-C methods but not C methods. A quick google for their [docs](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/native_interop/#Accessing_C_Methods_from_C) appears to agree with that.

Comment: @JustSid, So you are saying I can directly call a pure c method. If so, yes, I though that as well. Why I didn't choose that route I just described in "Additional info" section of the question text. Thanks for a tip though.

Comment: Check the Documentation page that I linked, it uses a different Syntax than you. I can't test it since I don't use C#/Xamarin, but it's probably worth a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how MonoTouch binds to Cocoa touch libraries, but I would try the following two approaches, in order, and see if one of them works:

First, I would try a class method, like this:

```
+(int)sprecFlacEncodeFromFile:(NSString*)wavFile toFile:(NSString*)flacFile;
```

If this does not bind properly, I would try using an instance method:

```
-(int)sprecFlacEncodeFromFile:(NSString*)wavFile toFile:(NSString*)flacFile;
```

In both cases the Cocoa wrapper function would need to pull C strings from `NSString` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `DllImport` to call the C function directly, it's *much* easier if you only have one function to call.

Unfortunatley your tool to generate it is wrong, it should be something like this:

```
[DllImport ("__Internal")]
static extern int Sprec_flac_encode (string wavfile, string flacfile);
```